# php/mqsql multiple calls to DB and multiple loops - different logic needed

Tags: php, optimization

Firstly let me apologise for my vague question title, this is my first post on this site; after spending 2 days searching for the answer to my question (and getting quite close in some cases) I've hit a wall. Normally I can find everything I need from stackoverflow but this time I've run out of ways to word my question in the search bar.

I have a mysql table containing data for clothes (tbl_clothing) and in this table (I've simplified this for my problem) I have columns: style, colour_url, size, carton_price

The 'style' is for a particulate type of garment $row['style'] in the first sql statement comes from the initial request to the database to find out if the users choice is actually a valid choice (don't worry I've sanitized it, no direct user input is ever used!)

I am grouping by colour_url to create an array of all the colour variations for the chosen style. Incidentally the colour_url is also the actual url to the image file for that colour (used later). Yes this does mean that in the database there is repeating data, the colour_url is repeated as many times as there are sizes for that colour - I've inherited it and can't change that yet.

I then iterate over this array 'foreach' of the different colours and perform another DB lookup to select all sizes and prices for the chosen style and the current colour.

Still in the above foreach loop I perform a while loop to create a second array to hold the sizes and prices (multiple rows are returned from the DB).

Still in the above foreach loop I perform another foreach loop on the second array to create the table structure for outputting.

This is now screaming at me that it is not the best way of achieving what I'm tying to do.

Am I just over thinking this or is there a much simpler way of doing things? I've tried doing a single sql lookup to retrieve a multidimensional array all in one hit but then cant separate out the data into correct groups I've been over and over transposing arrays re-looping through the array creating other "reference" arrays all without any success.

The basic logic works like this:
1 style = many colours
1 colour = many sizes
1 size = 1 price

And i'm trying to get a table output (for each colour) like this:
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**
|   (IMG A)   | Size(1)  | Size(2)   | Size(3)   |
| colour_A   | Price(1) | Price(2) | Price(3)  |
|***_*__*_*__*_*__**|__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__|

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___
|   (IMG B)   | Size(1)  | Size(2)   | Size(3)   |
| colour_B   | Price(1) | Price(2) | Price(3)  |
|***_*__*_*__*_*__**|__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__|

Here is my code, it does the job but this cant be the best way to do it:

```
$sql = "SELECT colour_url FROM tbl_clothing WHERE style = '".$row['style']."' GROUP BY colour_url";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$numRows = $result->num_rows;

if ($numRows != 0){
    while ($rowS = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $aResults[] = $rowS['colour_url'];
    }
    $result->free();

    foreach ($aResults as $k=>$v){
        echo "<table><tr><td rowspan='2'><img title='' alt='' src='".$v."' /></td>";

        $sql = "SELECT size, carton_price FROM tbl_clothing WHERE style = '".$row['style']."' AND colour_url = '".$v."'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        $numRows = $result->num_rows;

        if ($numRows != 0){
            $aSizePrice = array();
            while ($rowS = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $aSizePrice[$rowS['size']] = $rowS['carton_price'];
            }

            $sizes = "";
            $prices = "";
            foreach ($aSizePrice as $key=>$val){
                $sizes .= "<td>".$key."</td>";
                $prices .= "<td>".$val."</td>";
            }
        }
        $result->free();
        echo $sizes;
        echo "<tr>".$prices."</tr>";
        echo "</tr></table>";
    }
}
?>
```

Any help would be a hugely appreciated, even just a point in the right direction, a different opinion or even a sarcastic comment will do at this point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's start with your query.  In your first query, you claim you're trying to get all of the colors for a given style.  You can use the `DISTINCT` keyword for that

```
SELECT DISTINCT colour_url
  FROM tbl_clothing
  WHERE style = ?
```

But that's not what you're actually looking to get - you actually want all of the color/size combinations in your database for a given style, which you would likely want to select thusly:

```
SELECT colour_url, size, carton_price
  FROM tbl_clothing
  WHERE style = ?
```

Once you've done that, you want to parse it into a data structure.  (you should be parameterizing your queries - I recommend the PDO library, so I'll show you how that would work).

```
<?php
  $db = new PDO('connection', 'user', 'pass');
  $query = $db->prepare('SELECT colour_url, size, carton_price
                           FROM tbl_clothing
                           WHERE style = :style');
  $query->bindValue(':style', $row['style'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->execute();

  $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  $clothes = array();

  foreach($results as $result){
      if(!isset($clothes[$result['colour_url']]))
          $clothes[$result['colour_url']] = array();
      $clothes[$result['colour_url']][$result['size']] = $result['carton_price'];
  }
?>
```

Your results are now in a series of nested maps - from `$clothes[$color]`, you get a map from size to price.  `$clothes[$color][$size]` will net you the price of a specific color and size, and you can choose to print them that way:

```
<?php
  foreach($clothes as $color => $prices) {
    $sizeStr = '<td>' . implode('</td><td>', array_keys($prices)) . '</td>';
    $priceStr = '<td>' . implode('</td><td>', $prices) . '</td>';
    ?><table>
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
          <img title="" alt="" src="<?=$color?>" />
        </td>
        <?= $sizeStr ?>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <?= $priceStr ?>
      </tr>
    </table><?php
  }
?>
```

Your code now reads a lot closer to english, which will make it easier to debug, and easier to pas on to others.

Comment: thanks for your code & explanation, I'm really not wanting to use PDO as the rest of the site is using mqsqli - there are other queries on the same page using mysqli so I don't want to have 2 approaches in the same code - **HOWEVER** your response has led me down the right road and I now have the desired result, the multidimensional array you produced from the results set was the answer to my problem and slightly slicker than the first response so you get the accepted answer - thanks both of you for helping me out! P.s Is your code missing the $query->execute(); command?

Comment: @user3095078  Haha, yeah, I did forget to execute the query.  But when I said you should be using PDO, I really meant you should be using PDO  over the course of your entire codebase.  But I understand if you don't want to.  It does make your life easier, I must say, when you're using user supplied information.

Answer (score 2):

One thing i might recommend right off the bat, seperate your concerns. You are trying to get data right from the database into your view layer. Instead, get your data, compile it into memory, THEN, display it. It will make your problem easier to solve right off the start.

For example:

```
//Prepare the data receptacle
$data = array();

//Query to data to work with
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_clothing WHERE style = '".$row['style']."'");
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
while ($rowS = $result->fetch_assoc()){

    //Make sure our data can be stored correctly into our structure
    if(!isset($data[$row['style']])){ $data[$row['style']] = array(); }
    if(!isset($data[$row['style']][$rowS['colour_url'])){ $data[$row['style']][$rowS['colour_url'] = array(); }
    if(!isset($data[$row['style']][$rowS['colour_url']['sizes'])){ $data[$row['style']][$rowS['colour_url']['sizes'] = array(); }
    if(!isset($data[$row['style']][$rowS['colour_url']['prices'])){ $data[$row['style']][$rowS['colour_url']['prices'] = array(); }

    //Store the price and size
    $data[$row['style']][$rowS['colour_url']['sizes'][] = $rowS['size'];
    $data[$row['style']][$rowS['colour_url']['prices'][] = $rowS['carton_price'];

}

//At this point we have our data, let's just show it
?>
<table>
    <?php foreach($data as $style => $color_urls){ ?>
    <?php foreach($color_urls as $color_url => $content){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img title="" alt="" src="<?php echo $colour_url; ?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($content['sizes'] as $size){ ?>
        <td><?php echo $size; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($content['prices'] as $price){ ?>
        <td><?php echo $prices; ?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

This is just a quick draft, i might not have understood your question correctly, you'll have to fix the errors and the miscomprehensions yourself. At least you have a good start with this!

Comment: Hi thanks for your quick response, I'm looking over your thoughts and suggestions today. When I paste the above code into my editor it is suggesting there are syntax errors the first one on the line: if(!isset($data[$row['style']][$rowS['colour_url'])){ $data[$row['style']][$rowS['colour_url'] = array(); } should there be more square brackets closing after $rowS['colour_url']<- before the ))? when i add these in the code has no syntax errors but when run i get Warning: Illegal string offset 'sizes' in...that exact line of code???

Comment: That block just creates a receptacle for data, it should always be $data[something][somethingelse][somethingelse][etc] = "until the end";

Comment: If i'm missing a ], add it, i didn't test the code, it's all written off the counter

Comment: The point was to show you how to seperate your concerns to get a clearer code